# Delimiter at one side of a table

Tags: tables, delimiters

I have a huge table that needs some notes to do that i would like to have a huge curly bracket on the outer right side of the table.
I can not follow how this works: [align-large-vertical-delimiters-brackets-to-rows-of-a-table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218053/118709) but it seams to be exactly what i need.
especialy i do not see what this does at the point * multibrace[*3]: `\newcommand\multibrace[3]{\rdelim\}{#1}{3mm}[\pbox{#2}{#3}]}`

The table is this one: [im-searching-for-a-table-with-cdf-of-standard-normal-distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355575/118709)

Is it possible to get a delimiter on the fullheight of the outer right side of this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an environment using `array`. I have defined a table of two columns, the first one contains table content and the second one contains the braces and your desired text. In fact, there are two `tabluar`s within the main `tabluar` environment.

Here is your table as described (the table is filled using the data of your given link).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand\MyLBrace[2]{%
  \left.\rule{0pt}{#1}\right\}\text{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{lc@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllllllll}
z   & 0       & 0,01    & 0,02    & 0,03    & 0,04    & 0,05    & 0,06    & 0,07    & 0,08    & 0,09    \\
0   & 0,5     & 0,50399 & 0,50798 & 0,51197 & 0,51595 & 0,51994 & 0,52392 & 0,5279  & 0,53188 & 0,53586 \\
0,1 & 0,53983 & 0,5438  & 0,54776 & 0,55172 & 0,55567 & 0,55962 & 0,56356 & 0,56749 & 0,57142 & 0,57535 \\
0,2 & 0,57926 & 0,58317 & 0,58706 & 0,59095 & 0,59483 & 0,59871 & 0,60257 & 0,60642 & 0,61026 & 0,61409 \\
0,3 & 0,61791 & 0,62172 & 0,62552 & 0,6293  & 0,63307 & 0,63683 & 0,64058 & 0,64431 & 0,64803 & 0,65173 \\
0,4 & 0,65542 & 0,6591  & 0,66276 & 0,6664  & 0,67003 & 0,67364 & 0,67724 & 0,68082 & 0,68439 & 0,68793 \\
0,5 & 0,69146 & 0,69497 & 0,69847 & 0,70194 & 0,7054  & 0,70884 & 0,71226 & 0,71566 & 0,71904 & 0,7224  \\
0,6 & 0,72575 & 0,72907 & 0,73237 & 0,73565 & 0,73891 & 0,74215 & 0,74537 & 0,74857 & 0,75175 & 0,7549  \\
0,7 & 0,75804 & 0,76115 & 0,76424 & 0,7673  & 0,77035 & 0,77337 & 0,77637 & 0,77935 & 0,7823  & 0,78524 \\
0,8 & 0,78814 & 0,79103 & 0,79389 & 0,79673 & 0,79955 & 0,80234 & 0,80511 & 0,80785 & 0,81057 & 0,81327 \\
0,9 & 0,81594 & 0,81859 & 0,82121 & 0,82381 & 0,82639 & 0,82894 & 0,83147 & 0,83398 & 0,83646 & 0,83891 \\
1   & 0,84134 & 0,84375 & 0,84614 & 0,84849 & 0,85083 & 0,85314 & 0,85543 & 0,85769 & 0,85993 & 0,86214 \\
1,1 & 0,86433 & 0,8665  & 0,86864 & 0,87076 & 0,87286 & 0,87493 & 0,87698 & 0,879   & 0,881   & 0,88298 \\
1,2 & 0,88493 & 0,88686 & 0,88877 & 0,89065 & 0,89251 & 0,89435 & 0,89617 & 0,89796 & 0,89973 & 0,90147 \\
1,3 & 0,9032  & 0,9049  & 0,90658 & 0,90824 & 0,90988 & 0,91149 & 0,91309 & 0,91466 & 0,91621 & 0,91774 \\
1,4 & 0,91924 & 0,92073 & 0,9222  & 0,92364 & 0,92507 & 0,92647 & 0,92785 & 0,92922 & 0,93056 & 0,93189 \\
1,5 & 0,93319 & 0,93448 & 0,93574 & 0,93699 & 0,93822 & 0,93943 & 0,94062 & 0,94179 & 0,94295 & 0,94408 \\
1,6 & 0,9452  & 0,9463  & 0,94738 & 0,94845 & 0,9495  & 0,95053 & 0,95154 & 0,95254 & 0,95352 & 0,95449 \\
1,7 & 0,95543 & 0,95637 & 0,95728 & 0,95818 & 0,95907 & 0,95994 & 0,9608  & 0,96164 & 0,96246 & 0,96327 \\
1,8 & 0,96407 & 0,96485 & 0,96562 & 0,96638 & 0,96712 & 0,96784 & 0,96856 & 0,96926 & 0,96995 & 0,97062 \\
1,9 & 0,97128 & 0,97193 & 0,97257 & 0,9732  & 0,97381 & 0,97441 & 0,975   & 0,97558 & 0,97615 & 0,9767  \\
2   & 0,97725 & 0,97778 & 0,97831 & 0,97882 & 0,97932 & 0,97982 & 0,9803  & 0,98077 & 0,98124 & 0,98169 \\
2,1 & 0,98214 & 0,98257 & 0,983   & 0,98341 & 0,98382 & 0,98422 & 0,98461 & 0,985   & 0,98537 & 0,98574 \\
2,2 & 0,9861  & 0,98645 & 0,98679 & 0,98713 & 0,98745 & 0,98778 & 0,98809 & 0,9884  & 0,9887  & 0,98899 \\
2,3 & 0,98928 & 0,98956 & 0,98983 & 0,9901  & 0,99036 & 0,99061 & 0,99086 & 0,99111 & 0,99134 & 0,99158 \\
2,4 & 0,9918  & 0,99202 & 0,99224 & 0,99245 & 0,99266 & 0,99286 & 0,99305 & 0,99324 & 0,99343 & 0,99361 \\
2,5 & 0,99379 & 0,99396 & 0,99413 & 0,9943  & 0,99446 & 0,99461 & 0,99477 & 0,99492 & 0,99506 & 0,9952  \\
2,6 & 0,99534 & 0,99547 & 0,9956  & 0,99573 & 0,99585 & 0,99598 & 0,99609 & 0,99621 & 0,99632 & 0,99643 \\
2,7 & 0,99653 & 0,99664 & 0,99674 & 0,99683 & 0,99693 & 0,99702 & 0,99711 & 0,9972  & 0,99728 & 0,99736 \\
2,8 & 0,99744 & 0,99752 & 0,9976  & 0,99767 & 0,99774 & 0,99781 & 0,99788 & 0,99795 & 0,99801 & 0,99807 \\
2,9 & 0,99813 & 0,99819 & 0,99825 & 0,99831 & 0,99836 & 0,99841 & 0,99846 & 0,99851 & 0,99856 & 0,99861 \\
3   & 0,99865 & 0,99869 & 0,99874 & 0,99878 & 0,99882 & 0,99886 & 0,99889 & 0,99893 & 0,99896 & 0,999   \\
3,1 & 0,99903 & 0,99906 & 0,9991  & 0,99913 & 0,99916 & 0,99918 & 0,99921 & 0,99924 & 0,99926 & 0,99929 \\
3,2 & 0,99931 & 0,99934 & 0,99936 & 0,99938 & 0,9994  & 0,99942 & 0,99944 & 0,99946 & 0,99948 & 0,9995  \\
3,3 & 0,99952 & 0,99953 & 0,99955 & 0,99957 & 0,99958 & 0,9996  & 0,99961 & 0,99962 & 0,99964 & 0,99965 \\
3,4 & 0,99966 & 0,99968 & 0,99969 & 0,9997  & 0,99971 & 0,99972 & 0,99973 & 0,99974 & 0,99975 & 0,99976 \\
3,5 & 0,99977 & 0,99978 & 0,99978 & 0,99979 & 0,9998  & 0,99981 & 0,99981 & 0,99982 & 0,99983 & 0,99983 \\
3,6 & 0,99984 & 0,99985 & 0,99985 & 0,99986 & 0,99986 & 0,99987 & 0,99987 & 0,99988 & 0,99988 & 0,99989 \\
3,7 & 0,99989 & 0,9999  & 0,9999  & 0,9999  & 0,99991 & 0,99991 & 0,99992 & 0,99992 & 0,99992 & 0,99992 \\
3,8 & 0,99993 & 0,99993 & 0,99993 & 0,99994 & 0,99994 & 0,99994 & 0,99994 & 0,99995 & 0,99995 & 0,99995 \\
3,9 & 0,99995 & 0,99995 & 0,99996 & 0,99996 & 0,99996 & 0,99996 & 0,99996 & 0,99996 & 0,99997 & 0,99997 \\
4   & 0,99997 & 0,99997 & 0,99997 & 0,99997 & 0,99997 & 0,99997 & 0,99998 & 0,99998 & 0,99998 & 0,99998
\end{tabular}
& 
  $\begin{array}{l}
    \MyLBrace{60ex}{\rotatebox{90}{Here is the data that I want to present in my work.}} \\ 
  \end{array}$
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following table:

[image]