# Table Resizebox with lualatex

Tags: tables, luatex

I'm porting my original Latex file to include Lualatex code,  as I'm reading an input JSON file. I'm unable to get 'resizebox' to work with luacode, without it my table shows up but I want the table aligned to textwidth like in my original tex file. Any leads pelase?
JOSN:

```
{
   "ID":"ProjectionParams",
   "tableEntries":{
      "PROJECTION":"UNIVERSAL TRANSVERSE MERCATOR (UTM)",
      "SEMI-MAJOR":"0",
      "INVERSE FLATTENING OF REFERENCE ELLIPSOID":"0",
      "SCALE FACTOR ALONG THE CENTRAL MERIDIAN":"0",
      "WORLD MAGNETIC MODEL":"0"
   }
}
```

MAIN.Tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nohead,paperheight=11.0in,paperwidth=8.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

%%%%% dynamic table package %%%%%
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}% Set the separator between the columns.
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shapes.geometric,shadows,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=1.5mm,length=2mm]}}

%conditionals package
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  %cell height
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{FlushLeft}
ISOGONIC LINES PROGRAM
\end{FlushLeft}

\input{projection.tex}
\end{document}
```

projection.tex ( TEX):

```
\section*{PROJECTION PARAMETERS}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1,xshift=-7.5in]
    \draw (-0.04in,-0.22in) -- (7.54in,-0.27in); 
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

%%% Tex input to table %%%
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\hline
%row no:1

\multicolumn{1}{|p{3.55in}}{\textbf{PROJECTION}}& 
\multicolumn{1}{|p{3.55in}|}{\PROJECTION}\\
\hhline{--}
%row no:2

\multicolumn{1}{|p{3.55in}}{\textbf{SEMI-MAJOR AXIS OF REFERENCE ELLIPSOID (METERS):}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|p{3.55in}|}{\SEMIMAJOR} \\
\hhline{--}
\end{tabular}
}
 \end{table}
```

projection.tex (Lualatex ):

```
\section*{PROJECTION PARAMETERS}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1,xshift=-7.5in]
    \draw (-0.04in,-0.22in) -- (7.54in,-0.27in); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{luacode}
local json = require("json")
local file = io.open("data.json")
tab = json.parse(file:read("*all"))
file:close()

    tex.print("\\begin{table}[H]")
    tex.print("\\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%")
    tex.print("\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}")
    tex.print("\\hline")
    
    tex.print("{PROJECTION} &")
    tex.print(tab["tableEntries"]["PROJECTION"])
    tex.print("\\\\ \\hhline{--}")
    tex.print("{SEMI-MAJOR AXIS OF REFERENCE ELLIPSOID (METERS)} &")
    tex.print(tab["tableEntries"]["SEMI-MAJOR"])
    tex.print("\\\\ \\hhline{--}")
    
    tex.print("\\end{tabular}")
    tex.print("\\}")
    tex.print("\\end{table}")

\end{luacode}
```

End Table:
[image: protable]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make sure both columns ar enarrow enough to fit onto the page in the first place, instead of trying to scale the table, which would in turn lead to inconsistent font sizes?

Comment: Seomthing like `\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|}}
\hline
\textbf{PROJECTION}& 
\PROJECTION\\
\hhline{--}
\textbf{SEMI-MAJOR AXIS OF REFERENCE ELLIPSOID (METERS):} & 
\SEMIMAJOR \\
\hhline{--}
\end{tabular}` should result in a table that fits into the available space.

Comment: using `\resizebox` with tables should be avoided at all costs, it is bound to produce fonts and rule widths inconsistent with the rest of the document.

Comment: @leandriis thank you...this is very first document and since the table output in tex looked fitted with the page...I chose this approach...I'm unable to get lua to print the table when I try to include your suggestion to alter the table...error: invalid escape sequence near '"\{|*{2}{p{\d'.

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Which packages do you load? How or where are `\PROJECTION` and `\SEMIMAJOR` defined? Where might the `json` module be obtained from?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you David...what do u suggest that I try to align the table and text in lua?

Comment: I'd get the table sorted out in tex first the lua code is just obscuring things, for instance why is the tablular using `cc` and then every cell is usiing `\multicolumn` to replace that  by `p` ? If your table uses two `p` columns you know in advance how wide it is, so you can choose a width that fits so no scaling is needed.

Comment: I did *not* ask what's in the file `data.json`. I asked how to obtain the `json` module.

Comment: You should fix your example so people can run it and debug the issue. add a small but working json file and make the tex a complete document with `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: @Mico  using the json lua package from http://regex.info/blog/lua/json

Comment: no one can run the code posted or see the problem that you are seeing. Your main.tex has no documentclass for example. the lua seems to be unrelated to your question, it is just writing tex code so you could ask a question just using tex that asks about the table alignment.  `\resizebox` and  `tabular` etc are not handled by the lua code at all, to Lua it is just a string that is written to the tex document to be interpreted as tex.

Comment: apologies...I was too soon to save my edits and missed out a chunk of code...so the reason for having the lua code is I'm trying to build a dynamic table with the key value pairs in the json input file...so my first step was to see if I could print the tex code as is in lua that creates the table

Comment: But as shown in Mico's answer your actual question (as far as I can tell) is completely unrelated to Lua. Lua does not interpret the tex commands at all it just treats it as a string so once you know what latex you want to write, the question "how do I write this tex code from lua"  is the same whether you are writing tables or footnotes or tikz plots or anything else: just generate the tex code you want as a string then add it to the document with `tex.print` there is nothing special about tables in that step.

Comment: You still haven't answered my earlier question, about how `\PROJECTION` and `\SEMIMAJOR` are defined. (Aside: What's with the ALL-UPPERCASE stuff?) And your posting continues to provide no reason for why one might want to employ a `luacode` environment. Sadly, my mind-reading skills are simply worthless. Unless you start providing actionable information, the odds that someone will manage to figure what you're trying to achieve are bleak.

Comment: @Mico-
1. projection and semi major are defined in a .tex file  ----
\newcommand{\PROJECTION}{UNIVERSAL TRANSVERSE MERCATOR (UTM)}
\newcommand{\SEMIMAJOR}{6378137.000} ---
2. and the uppercase is how the mocked up  WORD report  that itry to rewrite in Latex
3. the reason for the luacode is read json file entries( cudnt do with plain tex) and loop through the objects to create a table with the json entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wish to create a table whose overall width is equal to `\textwidth` and which has two equally wide columns, both of which are supposed to allow automatic line wrapping. If this interpretation is correct, the `\resizebox`, the `c` column type, and the `\multicolumn` instructions are all superfluous and/or extraneous. Just load the `tabularx` package and use its eponymous environment.

Oh, and PLEASE DON'T USE ALL-CAPS TERMS -- UNLESS YOU WANT TO COME ACROSS AS WANTING TO SHOUT AT YOUR READERS.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\section*{Projection parameters}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{}}
\hline
\textbf{Projection} & Projection \\
\hline
\textbf{Semi-major axis of reference ellipsoid (meters)} & 
Semimajor \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico- also added the end table that I was working to get at in my original post... 
your example works for me.....my challenge is getting lua to print this to tex so  I can read json entries from the input file  and dynamically  fill the table contents.

Comment: is there a way to create the table rows on the fly on a condition then predefine the number of rows?

Comment: @24suns - for an example of how to use LuaLaTeX to populate the contents of an`array` environment programmatically, please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355599/5001) to the query [I'm searching for a table with cdf of standard normal distribution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/355574/5001). (Shameless-self-citation alert!)